# No module named 'PyPDF2' When Trying to Import

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-import, python-module

I am attempting to Import PyPDF2 in order to read a PDF file and parse through it. I am using a Raspberry Pi, and have installed PyPDF2 using the command `pip install PyPDF2`. However, when I try importing it, I am getting ModuleNotFoundError.

I think it may have installed it into the wrong location. When I do python -V it says I am using version 2.7.16. But the error states it's trying to look into the python3 folder?

I am attempting to import it using the line `import PyPDF2`

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/SqlDatabase.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PyPDF2
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

Any idea of how I can install PyPDF into the correct directory, or perhaps a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting the program with python3 (e.g. see if the first line of the file has `#!/usr/bin/python3` or similar), you need to install the library with `pip3`.

Comment: Wow, it was as easy as that! I just installed it with ```pip3 install PyPDF2``` and that did the trick. My first line was ```#!/usr/bin/env python```. I never would have guessed. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's interesting - so the default python at your system seems to be python3, but the default pip seems to be from python2.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying a whole bunch of stuff to try and fix it - I probably messed it up somewhere along the way. I will just remember to use pip3 to install things from here on out

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not installed PyPDF2 module in your device.

Execute following code in your terminal:

`pip install PyPDF2`

or

`pip3 install PyPDF2`

I think this will solve your problem. If this does not solve your problem, then there may be problem in your directory of python.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. Note that Python is a case-sensitive language.
While using the import command use **PyPDF2** and not **pyPDF2**

To install:

```
pipenv install PyPDF2
```

To import:

```
import PyPDF2
```

Answer (score 0):

inside `jupyternotebook`, open a file and type

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install PyPDF2
```

Installing directly `PyPDF2` from jupyer notebook rather than `anaconda`